# why Xcode didn't make addition?

Tags: swift, xcode

I use gm stepper in my app and , it corresponding to labels. I have 4 different labels and one additional label for addition to values . The labels which corresponding to GM Steppers working well but ı stumble in addition values of labels.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBAction func gmstp1(_ sender: GMStepper) {
    label1.text = String(sender.value*1.5)
    label6.text = String(sender.value)
}

@IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!


@IBAction func gmstp2(_ sender: GMStepper) {
    label2.text = String(sender.value*0.89)

}
@IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!


@IBAction func gmstp3(_ sender: GMStepper) {
    label3.text = String(sender.value*26)

}
@IBOutlet weak var label3: UILabel!


@IBAction func gmstp4(_ sender: GMStepper) {
    label4.text = String(sender.value*4)


}
@IBOutlet weak var label4: UILabel!

@IBOutlet weak var label5: UILabel!
```

My question about ; Is there any solution without using buttons? Could you handle that?

*Label5 using for summary.

Comment: What do you mean by " stumble in addition values of labels"? What code have you tried, and what's the error message?

Comment: I need to add first 4 four label each other and show the result in label5. I have tried many different types of code but label5 does not seem like a value by xcode. How can ı show that like a value?

Answer (score 0):

Simply because, unlike a `GMStepper`, a UILabel doesn't have a `value` property. So you'll have to get the `text` string in each label, convert it to a Double, and then add them up:

```
if let text1 = label1.text, let value1 = Double(text1),
    let text2 = label2.text, let value2 = Double(text2),
    let text3 = label3.text, let value3 = Double(text3),
    let text4 = label4.text, let value4 = Double(text4) {
    let sum = value1 + value2 + value3 + value4
    label5.text = String(sum)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response , it seem very sensible . I add them code in each stepper action but but now Xcode give some warnings and failed to build.

Comment: @B.Yılmaz what warnings are you getting and where?

Comment: "Initialization of immutable value 'value1' was never used; consider replacing with assignment to '_' or removing it." It warn that inside of the action lines.

Comment: @B.Yılmaz it is used `let sum = value1 + value2 + value3 + value4`

Comment: Thanks for that big help. Your codes work on button well but ı've tried to show sum without button. It should show result continuously..

Comment: If my answer helped you and solved your first problem, do mark it as the accepted answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers . If you have more question, it would be appropriate to ask them in a new question