# How can I perform addition automatically in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, e-commerce

I work on a e-commerce project and now designing basket page. I create 4 steppers for determine to quantity of products. I create labels for show cost of each products and one label for total cost.

```
@IBOutlet weak var label1: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var label2: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var label3: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var label4: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var label5: UILabel!

@IBAction func GmS1(_ sender: GMStepper) {
    label1.text = String(sender.value*1.5)
}

@IBAction func GmS2(_ sender: GMStepper) {
    label2.text = String(sender.value*0.89)
}

@IBAction func GmS3(_ sender: GMStepper) {
    label3.text = String(sender.value*26)
}

@IBAction func GmS4(_ sender: GMStepper) {
    label4.text = String(sender.value*4)
}
```

I don't want to use button but I struggling in addition total cost automatically. My codes are above. Are there anybody know : How can ı addition 4 label in 1 label automatically(without any button).

- Label5 for total cost.
- You can check photo for general idea.

[image: General Idea of Page]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continuing from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52205941/why-xcode-didnt-make-addition):

```
@IBAction func gmstp1(_ sender: GMStepper) {
    label1.text = String(sender.value * 1.5)
    calculateSum()
}

@IBAction func gmstp2(_ sender: GMStepper) {
    label2.text = String(sender.value * 0.89)
    calculateSum()
}

@IBAction func gmstp3(_ sender: GMStepper) {
    label3.text = String(sender.value * 26.0)
    calculateSum()
}

@IBAction func gmstp4(_ sender: GMStepper) {
    label4.text = String(sender.value * 4.0)
    calculateSum()
}
```

Where `calculateSum` is a function defined like so:

```
func calculateSum() {
    if let text1 = label1.text, let value1 = Double(text1),
        let text2 = label2.text, let value2 = Double(text2),
        let text3 = label3.text, let value3 = Double(text3),
        let text4 = label4.text, let value4 = Double(text4) {
        let sum = value1 + value2 + value3 + value4
        label6.text = String(sum)
    }
}
```

Or if you'd prefer a one-liner:

```
func calculateSum() {
    label5.text = String([label1, label2, label3, label4].reduce(0,{$0 + (Double($1.text ?? "0") ?? 0)}))
}
```

Comment: It work well when write label5 instead of label6 but there is some problem , stepper have two button (- , +). Both button doing addition but (-) button should do subtraction and initial cost shouldn't be zero because there is 4 product.

Comment: How can ı give initial cost? In this situation , ı have to push two button at least for addition.

Comment: @B.Yılmaz `label5.text = "0"`

Comment: After ı have updated Mojave and new Xcode ,                                            func calculateSum() {
    label5.text = String([label1, label2, label3, label4].reduce(0,{$0 + (Double($1.text ?? "0") ?? 0)}))
} This function give an error like : The compiler is unable to type-check this expression in reasonable time; try breaking up the expression into distinct sub-expressions . Do you know something about it?

Answer (score 1):

Make a function sumValues, add all the label's value in it, and assign string of sum to `label5.text`. This function can be then called from all the IBAction

```
@IBAction func GmS4(_ sender: GMStepper) {
    label4.text = String(sender.value*4)
    sumValues()
}
```

In the function `sumValues()`,
set `label5.text =` string of sum of all the labels'.

**SideNote** - Make sure to initialize value of all labels to 0 in `viewDidLoad()`.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to call this method from every action

```
func sumAll() {
   let sum = [label1,label2,label3,label4].map { Int($0.text ?? "0" ) ?? 0 }.reduce(0,+) 
   label5.text = "\(sum)" 
}
```

**Note:** if word **variable** is part of the label text you may extract number from the text or declare the steppers as outlets and ask them about their current value and at this way use

```
let sum = [stepper1,stepper2,stepper3,stepper4].map{$0.value}.reduce(0,+)
```

Comment: Thanks for comment. Each stepper has different constant so ı've to use label as outlet. This method work in first increase or decrease of steppers but in next changes doesn't work.